# Throw an exception showing differences

Tags: python, json, pytest

I'm creating a function that executes after some tests that generates an output file. I want to check that the output in memory for a process has differences with a previous test run and If there is any difference then shows the differences in the tests logs and tests fails.

```
with open(os.path.join(path, f"{test_name}.json"), "r") as local_file:
     local_data = json.loads(local_file.read())
     differences = jsondiff.diff(local_data, payload["args"][1])
     if differences:
        print(differences)
        raise ValueError("There are some differences with {test_name}.json file")
```

This shows me in the test logs the following output.
[image]

But I don't want to show this, I want to show the differences and the test_name.

Should I need to add an assert in this method or create a customer exception?

Comment: You tried to use `f-string` syntax in a normal string.  You need to choose one format or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your string to be an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

```
with open(os.path.join(path, f"{test_name}.json"), "r") as local_file:
     local_data = json.loads(local_file.read())
     differences = jsondiff.diff(local_data, payload["args"][1])
     if differences:
        print(differences)
        raise ValueError(f"There are some differences with {test_name}.json file")
#This                    ^
#Is what you were missing
```